# How to configure log4j for an xtext gradle build?

Tags: gradle, log4j, xtext, xtext-gradle-plugin

When I start the gradle build in one of my modules, it prints an error-message to std-error:

```
:m28_presentation_api:generateXtext
Error initializing JvmElement
```

That's not very helpful and I hope, that I can configure log4j to print more details about the exception.
I think this message is logged by [JvmTypesBuilder.initializeSafely()](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/blob/v2.13.0/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/src/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/jvmmodel/JvmTypesBuilder.java#L213)

```
LOG.error("Error initializing JvmElement", e);
```

Versions:

- I am using xtext 2.13: in the [MANIFEST.MF](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/blob/v2.13.0/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#L122) file, I see the
- log4j version: 1.2.15
- gradle version: 4.6
- [xtext-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin) version: 1.0.21

According to the [log4j V1 docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_Procedure), it should be enough when I add a `log4j.properties` file to the classpath: so I just save this file in `src/main/java`.
But it seems that this is not used/found - or maybe I did something wrong in the configuration file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=stderr
log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

When I now start the build, I'd expect a different log-output for the error-message, but it prints the same message as before. So obviously my log-config is not used for some reasons.

What am I missing?
Or can someone maybe point me to an example project?

Comment: what does `--stacktrace` print (if added to gradle invokation)

Comment: the gradle `--stacktrace` flag, does not help, since [JvmTypesBuilder.initializeSafely](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/blob/v2.13.0/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/src/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/jvmmodel/JvmTypesBuilder.java#L213) only logs the Exception, but it does not reraise it.

Comment: hmmm then the question is: who logs the exception but not the cause. i would have hoped that --stacktrace gives you the catcher. or does it simply log the message and the run through?

Comment: didn't I just say that in my previous comment? 
[JvmTypesBuilder.initializeSafely](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/blob/v2.13.0/org.eclipse.xtext.xbase/src/org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/jvmmodel/JvmTypesBuilder.java#L213) only logs the Exception, but it does not reraise it: so `--stacktrace` does not help. But since `LOG.error("Error initializing JvmElement", e);` is called, I think, log4j has all the info and could print a stacktrace, if configured correctly.

Comment: well do you have anything that lets me reproduce this? does the same problem happen in eclipse?

Comment: Unfortunately not: I cannot even reproduce this in my unit-tests (yet). 
Moreover it is an Android project, so I cannot use Eclipse (Buildship crashes when importing the gradle projects).

Comment: btw is there a reason you use the old style inferrer? ill try to create a sample myself

Comment: I was not aware that there are different inferrers. Can you please post a link to some docs, or examples of the new one?

Comment: i mean you call accept(toXXX(name,[])) instead of accept(toXXX(name),[])

Comment: Ah - now I see. there are 2 overloads of accept - one is deprecated. Unfortunatley the xtend editor does not show the deprecation warning. I think the `@Deprecated` annotation should be on the `IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor.IPostIndexingInitializing<T> accept(T type);` function.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like LOG.error() does not print a stacktrace by default. maybe you can actively change your code e.g.

```
class MyDslJvmModelInferrer extends AbstractModelInferrer {

    @Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyDslJvmModelInferrer);


    def dispatch void infer(Model element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        acceptor.accept(element.toClass(element.name, [
            try {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("mimimi")

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace
                throw e
            }
        ]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is also a helpful workaround:but since I have many such methods, I'd need a try-catch everywhere. I found another way that makes it easier in my case - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but a workaround (maybe helpful for others).

I gave up on the log4j configuration after wasting some hours and applied this workaround which took only some minutes and revealed the real problem.

What I've done, is to create my own `JvmTypesBuilder`, override the `initializeSafely` method and directly print the stack-trace to `stderr`:

```xtend
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmTypesBuilder
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Procedures.Procedure1
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

class JvmTypesBuilderTm extends JvmTypesBuilder {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JvmTypesBuilder)

    // TODO: nasty workaround because I cannot figure out how to configure the logging correctly
    override <T extends EObject> initializeSafely(T targetElement, Procedure1<? super T> initializer) {
        if(targetElement !== null && initializer !== null) {
            try {
                initializer.apply(targetElement);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error initializing JvmElement: "+targetElement.toString, e);
                e.printStackTrace
            }
        }
        return targetElement;
    }
}
```

Then I just replaced all occurrences of the `JvmTypesBuilder` in my code with the new one. With the stacktrace, it was easy to find the real issue in my code.